Swift Lightstreamer SDK stuck on connecting
I'm certainly missing something obvious but I can't figure it out.
I'm trying to get the Lightstreamer sdk to work on a macOS project in swift.
Everything compiles perfectly and runs without errors but the log systematically indicates Status: CONNECTING.
Stranger still, if I indicate a url which is not a Lightstreamer server the behavior is the same, no error in the logs, just "connecting" for ever.
HTTP requests via URLSession work without problems.
class TestSDK{
    let delegateTest = SubscriptionDelegateImpl()
    let loggerProvider = ConsoleLoggerProvider(level: .debug)
    
    init(){
        LightstreamerClient.setLoggerProvider(loggerProvider)
        
        let client = LightstreamerClient(serverAddress: "https://push.lightstreamer.com/", adapterSet: "DEMO")
        client.connect()
        
        let items = [ "item1", "item2", "item3" ]
        let fields = [ "stock_name", "last_price" ]
        let sub = Subscription(subscriptionMode: .MERGE, items: items, fields: fields)
        sub.dataAdapter = "QUOTE_ADAPTER"
        sub.requestedSnapshot = .yes
        sub.addDelegate(delegateTest)
        client.subscribe(sub)
    }
}

and the logs :
serverAddress changed: https://push.lightstreamer.com/
adapterSet changed: DEMO
Connection requested: details: [serverAddress: https://push.lightstreamer.com/, adapterSet: DEMO, libVersion: swift_client 6.1.1] options: [requestedMaxBandwidth: unlimited, retryDelay: 4000, firstRetryMaxDelay: 100, sessionRecoveryTimeout: 15000, stalledTimeout: 2000, reconnectTimeout: 3000, idleTimeout: 19000, contentLength: 50000000]
Status: CONNECTING
WS connecting: https://push.lightstreamer.com/lightstreamer Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: TLCP-2.5.0.lightstreamer.com
subscriptionDidAddDelegate called
Subscription requested: subId: 1 [mode: MERGE, items: ["item1", "item2", "item3"], fields: ["stock_name", "last_price"], dataAdapter: QUOTE_ADAPTER, requestedSnapshot: yes]


Who print the status? Shouldn't SubscriptionDelegateImpl() be kept in memory? It might be deallocated too soon. Are the delegate method printing it?

The status come from the ConsoleLoggerProvider. The delegate method subscription(_ subscription: Subscription, didUpdateItem itemUpdate: ItemUpdate) were never called, only subscriptionDidAddDelegate(_ subscription: Subscription)

Make SubscriptionDelegateImpl() a var and a property of your object, if it's released to soon (ie becomes nil), then the delegate method won't be called.

Thanks for your help, appreciate it, but did it and no change...

And is TestSDK hold into memory too?

Yes it's a strong reference too. I did the simplest exemple possible, literally the exact same as the starting point on the GitHub page of the sdk.

I found the solution with your help! The weak reference was on the Lightstreamer instance and was garbage collected too soon. Thank you for pointing out in the correct direction!

Found the solution thanks to you.
As I suspected, it was a newbie mistake, coming from a different language I didn't thought the garbage collector was this quick...
class TestSDK{
let delegateTest = SubscriptionDelegateImpl()
let loggerProvider = ConsoleLoggerProvider(level: .debug)
var client:LightstreamerClient // solution here, strong reference 

init(){
    LightstreamerClient.setLoggerProvider(loggerProvider)
    
    client = LightstreamerClient(serverAddress: "https://push.lightstreamer.com/", adapterSet: "DEMO")
    client.connect()
    
    let items = [ "item1", "item2", "item3" ]
    let fields = [ "stock_name", "last_price" ]
    let sub = Subscription(subscriptionMode: .MERGE, items: items, fields: fields)
    sub.dataAdapter = "QUOTE_ADAPTER"
    sub.requestedSnapshot = .yes
    sub.addDelegate(delegateTest)
    client.subscribe(sub)
}

}

There is no garbage collector (which is a "live tool when app is running"). Instead it's ARC, that will add "object.release()" at the end of each needed scopes (to simplify at the closing }of the method, the loop, the if test, etc.)

Thanks again for your response. Make sense now.
